# Is there a way to clone a repo without creating the containing directory?

Tags: git, git-clone

I have this file structure:

```
folderIWantStuffIn/
  - old_stuff
```

Now I want to add some new stuff that is in a git repo. I'd like to be able to use `git clone` and `git pull` right in the directory and get this:

```
folderIWantStuffIn/
  - old_stuff
  - new_stuff
```

When I use `git clone`, I get this:

```
folderIWantStuffIn/
  - old_stuff
  - NewStuffFolder/
      - new_stuff
```

Are there flags I can pass into `git clone` to get this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `git clone $URL .` The magic there is the `.`—it tells git the directory into which it should clone the repo (in this case, we're using `.`, aka, the current directory). See [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) for more options.

Comment: That's clever, I like it. Is there anyway to use this if there are already files in the directory?

Comment: I don't see an easy way, but there's nothing stopping you from temporarily moving the files to a different directory and then moving them back after you you clone the repo, right?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a way to distribute a plugin, so I was hoping to be able to give out an easy command. Anyway....good enough for the check....thanks